# NopCommerce 4.3 Error Page redirected you too many times

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, nopcommerce

I have installed SSL certificate for my domain on shared server. But after installing the SSL, when I enable SSL from admin panel, cart and admin panel show the error "Redirected you too many times" and at the same time lock indicating secured connection shows with the url.

When I disabled SSL again from the database, all pages are working fine but url is showing not secure.
Home page works in both cases.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can ensure your SSL certificate is not valid. Is it godaddy?

Comment: Where did you get your SSL? How are you hosting your website (IIS, unix, etc. . )

Comment: For me, I am getting same error while debugging.

Comment: I enabled Configuration > Stores SSL enabled and got the same error you did. I turned it back off through the database and it worked with http:// or https://.  Set the store URL to https:// store.url and it now forces https:// by default, even though SSL enabled = false. According to the release notes, 4.40 has force SSL by default now. Also, my host uses Cloudfare and it seems there is extra stuff to do. The bottom line is, I don't have "SSL enabled" checked and http:// is auto redirecting to https://. Best info I found was here: https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/4641